# That's a lot of threes

Tags: cipher

> 33333334333333393333333233333330333333343334333333333334333333393333333433343332333333343333333533333332333333303333333533333334333333353333333533333335333333323333333533333334333333343334333333333334333333353333333533333333

Decrypt that to get a <s>funny</s> message.

Comment: If it's not funny, I'm not decrypting anything.

Comment: In case this is some kind of unary with separators, this is the number of 3s separated by non-3s: `7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 3, 11, 7, 7, 3, 3, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 3, 11, 7, 7`. And that's a lot of 7s.

Comment: Which means it's in the format "333x"*n+333 for an integer n, and x in some digit

Comment: Nope, not even close. Its really easy once u solve it.

Comment: I'll write my answer in 7 days if no one gets it. But I trust that someone will.

Comment: The fact that you wrote funny and then striked it out is already funny in itself.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> The message is simply encoded several times as a hex representation of the corresponding ASCII value. Transforming the message the first time gives this:
>
>  `3334333933323330333434333334333933343432333433353332333033353334333533353335333233353334333434333334333533353333`
>
>  The next step:
>
>  `34393230344334393442343532303534353535323534344334353533`
>
>  One more:
>
>   `49204C494B4520545552544C4553`
>
>  And finally:
>
>  [`I LIKE TURTLES`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CMNry4PE93Y)

Comment: Would funnier if that was purely coincidence.

Comment: LOL You got it. I told ya'll it was easy!

Comment: I wonder, how did you see through the pattern? Have you come across something similar before?

Comment: @Reti43 If you look at the ASCII codes for all digits its pretty obvious. You simply remove threes in the first three steps.

Comment: @Reti43 And yes, I knew that digits are encoded like this in ASCII.